# I need to increase the performance of query

Tags: mysql

it worked fine for  10000 records but for 2300000 records it not working,how I have handle this type of query to increase performance pls help I am fresher to this mysql

```
 select 
  r1.countrycode,
  r1.code,
  r1.rate,
  f.cdr_id,
  f.cld,
  f.direction,
  from 
  rates1 r1, 
  calls f 
     where(r1.code,f.cld) in 
     (select 
     max(r1.code),
     f.cld 
     from rates1 r1, calls f 
     where (f.cld regexp concat('^',r1.code,'[0-9]+$'))
     group by f.cld
```

);

```
Sub query returns the Unique values for code and cld and main query use the code and cld in where
condition and result the all the values  

calls table data
cdr_id      cld     direction duration 
 1      1985484555  incoming    59
 2      8475858585  outgoing    456
 3      1895858888  outgoing    555 
 4      1548458455  incomimg    895
 5      548585665   incoming    585
 6      1985484555  outgoing    585

 rates1 table data
 countryocde   code     rate
 040            19854   0.35
 080            198     0.356
 578            847     0.25
 458            1548    0.50
 555            1548    0.75
```

HI friends, i write this Query to pick the unique values for the Code and cld colums for the 2 tables its working fine in my less number of records and it not excuting for more than 1000000 records its executing for longtime with out give any result,pls help Thanks in advance.

Comment: include the result of an `explain select....`

Comment: Sub query returns the Unique values for code and cld and main query use the code and cld  in where condition and result the all the values

Comment: In first place, I'd use `f.cld LIKE concat(r1.code, '%')` instead of `f.cld regexp concat('^',r1.code,'[0-9]+$')` as regular expressions can be harmful in queries.
I'd like to give you an real answer to your question, but have some issues understanding ist.

Comment: HI rene Hoffmann , I have to compare the code in rates1 table with cld with the calls table then after I have to get the corresponding rate to cld in calls table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with getting the country code:

```
select c.*,
       (select countrycode
        from rates1 r1
        where c.cld like concat(r1.code, '%')
        order by length(r1.code) desc
       limit 1
      ) as countrycode
from calls c;
```

Then, join the rates information back in:

```
select *
from (select c.*,
             (select r1.code
              from rates1 r1
              where c.cld like concat(r1.code, '%')
              order by length(r1.code) desc
             limit 1
            ) as r1code
      from calls c
     ) c join
     rates1 r
     on c.r1code = r.code
```

This will still have poor performance, but it will be better than two cartesian products.

You can made this perform faster with an index on the `rates1(code)` and a process like:

```
select c.*, coalesce(r5.countrycode, r4.countrycode, r3.countrycode, r2.countrycode, r1.countrycode) as countrycode
from calls c left join
     rates1 r1
     on r1.code = left(c.code, 1) left join
     rates1 r2
     on r2.code = left(c.code, 2) left join
     rates1 r3
     on r3.code = left(c.code, 3) left join
     rates1 r4
     on r4.code = left(c.code, 4) left join
     rates1 r5
     on r5.code = left(c.code, 5);
```

You need enough joins for the longest length of possible codes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it c1 or c in the last join statement

Comment: @Bala . . . I fixed that oversight.  It occurs to me that more than one country code might have the same prefix, so I adjusted the logic to use `rates1.code` instead of country code.